# Fastest way to extract a model object from fit_resamples() results

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidymodels

This question if for tidymodels user, and if you are lazy, just skip the entire text and jump right to the bold question below

Im looking for the most efficient way to extract my parsnip model object from fitted resamples (`tune::fit_resample()`).

When i want to train a model with cross-validation, i can either go with `tune::tune_grid()` oder `fit_resamples()`.

Lets say i know the best parameters for my algorithm, so i dont need any paramter tunig, which means i decide to go with `fit_resamples()`.
If i had decided to go with `tune_grid()` i usually set up a workflow since i evaluate different models after tune_grid ran: I go for `tune::show_best()` and `tune::select_best()` to explore and extract the best parameters for my model. Then i go for `tune::finalize_workflow()`, `workflows::pull_wokrflow_fit()` to extract my model object. Further when i want to see predictions i go for `tune::last_fit()` and `tune::collect_predictions()`

All these steps seem redundant when i go with `fit_resamples()`, since i basically only have one model with stable parameters. So all these steps above are not neccesarry, nevertheless i have to go trough them. Do I?

After `fit_resamples()` is performed, i get a tibble with information about .splits, .metrics, .notes, etc.
So my question really comes down to:

- **What is the fastest way from the output tibble of `fit_resamples()` to my final parsnip model object?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to realize about `fit_resamples()` is that its purpose is to **measure performance**. The models that you train in `fit_resamples()` are not kept or used later.

Let's imagine that you know the parameters you want to use for an SVM model.

```r
library(tidymodels)
#> ── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────── tidymodels 0.1.1 ──
#> ✓ broom     0.7.0      ✓ recipes   0.1.13
#> ✓ dials     0.0.8      ✓ rsample   0.0.7 
#> ✓ dplyr     1.0.0      ✓ tibble    3.0.3 
#> ✓ ggplot2   3.3.2      ✓ tidyr     1.1.0 
#> ✓ infer     0.5.3      ✓ tune      0.1.1 
#> ✓ modeldata 0.0.2      ✓ workflows 0.1.2 
#> ✓ parsnip   0.1.2      ✓ yardstick 0.0.7 
#> ✓ purrr     0.3.4
#> ── Conflicts ────────────────────────────── tidymodels_conflicts() ──
#> x purrr::discard() masks scales::discard()
#> x dplyr::filter()  masks stats::filter()
#> x dplyr::lag()     masks stats::lag()
#> x recipes::step()  masks stats::step()

## pretend this is your training data
data("hpc_data")

svm_spec <- svm_poly(degree = 1, cost = 1/4) %>%
  set_engine("kernlab") %>%
  set_mode("regression")

svm_wf <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(svm_spec) %>%
  add_formula(compounds ~ .)

hpc_folds <- vfold_cv(hpc_data)

svm_rs <- svm_wf %>%
  fit_resamples(
    resamples = hpc_folds
  )

svm_rs
#> # Resampling results
#> # 10-fold cross-validation 
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>    splits             id     .metrics         .notes          
#>    <list>             <chr>  <list>           <list>          
#>  1 <split [3.9K/434]> Fold01 <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#>  2 <split [3.9K/433]> Fold02 <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#>  3 <split [3.9K/433]> Fold03 <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#>  4 <split [3.9K/433]> Fold04 <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#>  5 <split [3.9K/433]> Fold05 <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#>  6 <split [3.9K/433]> Fold06 <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#>  7 <split [3.9K/433]> Fold07 <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#>  8 <split [3.9K/433]> Fold08 <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#>  9 <split [3.9K/433]> Fold09 <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#> 10 <split [3.9K/433]> Fold10 <tibble [2 × 3]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
```

There are no fitted models in this output. Models were fitted to each of these resamples, but you don't want to use them for anything; they are thrown away because their only purpose is for computing the `.metrics` to estimate performance.

If you want a model to use to predict on new data, you need to go back to your whole training set and fit your model once again, with the entire training set.

```r
svm_fit <- svm_wf %>%
  fit(hpc_data)

svm_fit
#> ══ Workflow [trained] ═══════════════════════════════════════════════
#> Preprocessor: Formula
#> Model: svm_poly()
#> 
#> ── Preprocessor ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> compounds ~ .
#> 
#> ── Model ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Support Vector Machine object of class "ksvm" 
#> 
#> SV type: eps-svr  (regression) 
#>  parameter : epsilon = 0.1  cost C = 0.25 
#> 
#> Polynomial kernel function. 
#>  Hyperparameters : degree =  1  scale =  1  offset =  1 
#> 
#> Number of Support Vectors : 2827 
#> 
#> Objective Function Value : -284.7255 
#> Training error : 0.835421
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This final object is one that you can use with `pull_workflow_fit()` for variable importance or similar.

Comment: Thank You! I have a further (maybe dumb) question: Once you call ``fit_resamples()`` on ``svm_wf`` you get a 10-fold cross-validation tibble as output and you said the .metric column of this tibble is what you want to pay attention to as it gives you information about rmse and rsq. 
What iam wondering about, is: the rmse and rsq will most likely vary a lot for each fold, so you have 10 different measurements for your model. What kind of additional value does this give to you?

Comment: The value it gives you there is a measure of both the center and spread of, say, RMSE and R^2. You can measure how much it varies from this, and have a better estimate of the central value.